# Quadradic recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

There is an method to solve recurrences of the form $a_{n+1} = (a_n + c)^2$?
I am particularly interested when $c = 1$.

I tried to use generating functions but I got stuck with.
Let $G(x) = \sum_{k \geq 0} a_k x^k$, then:

$$ x G(x) = x a_0 + \sum_{k \geq 1} a_k x^{k+1} = xa_0 + \sum_{k \geq 0} a_{k+1} x^k$$
$$ x G(x) = x a_0 + \sum_{k \geq 0} (a_n + c)^2 x^k  = xa_0 + \sum_{k \geq 0} (a_n^2 + 2c a_n + c^2 ) x^k $$
$$ x G(x) = x a_0 + 2cG(x)+\frac{c^2}{1-x} + \sum_{k \geq 0} a_n^2 x^k$$

I don't know what to do with the squared coefficients. Another approach is welcome!

Comment: Generating functions won't work. Nonlinear recurrences can have extremely complicated behavior in general; see, for example, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticMap.html.

Comment: I also think that the generating function won't work for these type of nonlinear recurrence relations.Try the following method. I think it will work for your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: I also think that the generating function won't work. Try this one. I think it will work for your problem]
b_n=((((〖b_0〗^2+1)^2+1)^2+1)^2+ …)^2+1

Comment: May I ask where is this taking you ?

Comment: I think it is right. I couldn't find a mistake. Is there any thing wrong?

Comment: There's nothing wrong, it just doesn't seem very helpful to say, you calculate the $n$ term by calculating the $n$th term.

Comment: You are right. But I couldn't find a another method. I think if we can transform to a system of linear recurrence relations it would be a better solution.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, this gives you $b_n \approx \theta^{\left( 2^n \right)}$ up to a constant factor, but you cannot find $\theta$ explicitly, only estimate. The two explicit are $x_{n+1} = x_n^2 $ and $x_{n+1} = x_n^2 -2,$ from the Lucas-Lehmer test and Lucas Sequences.

Comment: For the curious, for $x_{n+1} = x_n^2 - 2,$ with $x_0 > 2,$ let $A > B > 0,$ $A+B = x_0,$ $AB = 1.$ Then $$ x_n = A^{\left( 2^n \right)} + B^{\left( 2^n \right)} $$

Comment: @WillJagy can you explain how did you get the asymptotic?

Comment: @NilanC.Manoj I accepted your answer because maybe we can't do any more than that, but you didn't 'solve' the recursion...

Comment: $\log \theta = \lim b_n / 2^n.$ The more $b_n$ you calculate the better estimate of $\log \theta$ and $\theta,$ still unsatisfying.